# How to customise HTML markup generated by ValidationMessageFor in MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, model-validation

I am working on a MVC 4 project which requires to generate a specific markup when there is any error raise by the model validation.

suppose :

```
<div><i class="fa fa-info"></i><span>Error Message</span><div>
```

I have tried jquery to update the markup required on the event but that makes the code complex as too many client side events need attach on the DOM elements.

Thanks

**Edit :** Razor view engine generate a specific markup for

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ModelProperty)
```

I want to customize the markup generated by the Razor View Engine for the above helper method without affecting the validation functionality.

Comment: what exactly is your need

Comment: What do you want to change your HTML to? The question is unclear.

Comment: You would need to write your own HtmlHelper extension method. ut why not just use css to style the `<span>` element that `ValidationMessageFor()` generates?

Answer (score 0):

The css class name for MVC validation message block is : `.validation-summary-errors`. You could find it easily with F12 inspector. So :

```
$(document).ready() {
   $('.validation-summary-errors').html('<span>' + $('.validation-summary-errors').html() + '</span>')
   $('.validation-summary-errors').prepend('<i class="fa fa-info"></i>') ; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i don't want to manipulate DOM elements from jquery/javascript